# Tkinter window resizing does not work even with sticky() and columnconfigure() - rasberry pi running rasbian

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

I am trying to do a simple GUI with buttons and a title. I am currently coding on a rasberry pi running on rasbian (a modified version of linux darbian). When I try to resize the window I create it behaves like nothing happened and disappears because the window is too small. I do the same as in other tutorials. Here is my code :

```
content = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(3,3,12,12))
    content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

    frame = ttk.Frame(content, height=500, width=900)
    frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=3, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

    title = ttk.Label(content, text="QRNG")
    title.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N))

    diceButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Dice")
    diceButton.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W))

    imageButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Image")
    imageButton.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=())

    randomNumberButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Random Numbers")
    randomNumberButton.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(E))

    fileButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Random Number File")
    fileButton.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(S, W))

    otherButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Empty")
    otherButton.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(S))

    exitButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Exit")
    exitButton.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(S, E))

    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=80)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=80)

    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=80)
    root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=80)
    root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1, minsize=80)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=80)
    root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=80)
    root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1, minsize=80)
```

Sorry for the big block, but I cannot traceback what is causing this problem. The sticky works when the GUI is launched but after nothing works anymore and the GUI is static. Even stranger, I copy pasted the example from this web page and it worked but when I try to apply this to my own code it doesn't work. I took the code from the end of [this web page](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html#resize).
I would greatly apreciate any help given. Just in case I took of a couple of options from the buttons that, I think, weren't important for understanding the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, every time you use `grid` you should give at least one row and one column a weight in the containing widget. You've done that for the root widget but you haven't done it for `content` or `frame`.

The other problem is that you only have widgets in row 0, column 0 of the root window, yet you've configured the weights of row and column 0-3.

So, assuming that you want `content` to fill the entire window, remove the configuration of rows 1 and 2 and columns 1 and 2 in the root window.

Inside `content` you are putting widgets in rows 0-3 and columns 0-3. Assuming you want the contents of those rows and columns spaced out equally, you should give each row and column an equal weight. By the look of your code, it looks like you maybe were trying to do that, but did it on the root window instead of on `content`.

The following example includes those modifications. I've also reorganized your code to make it more readable. In my experience it's best to group  all of the layout commands for each group of widgets together. It makes it much easier to visualize the final layout, and easier to make adjustments.

```
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=80)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=80)

content = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(3,3,12,12))
content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

content.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=80)
content.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=80)
content.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=80)
content.columnconfigure(2, weight=1, minsize=80)
content.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=80)
content.rowconfigure(2, weight=1, minsize=80)

frame = ttk.Frame(content, height=500, width=900)
title = ttk.Label(content, text="QRNG")
diceButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Dice")
imageButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Image")
randomNumberButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Random Numbers")
fileButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Random Number File")
otherButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Empty")
exitButton = ttk.Button(content, text="Exit")

frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=3, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
title.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N))
diceButton.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W))
imageButton.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=())
randomNumberButton.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(E))
fileButton.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(S, W))
otherButton.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(S))
exitButton.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(S, E))
```

Comment: Because I copy+pasted everything I forgot to specify the widget. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Jonathcraft: that's one reason why you shouldn't copy and paste code from the internet. Typing it out helps you to better understand the code.